# access of undefined property event

Tags: flash, actionscript, compiler-construction, adobe

I keep getting "access of undefined property event"
Cant seem to figure it out and im guessing its something small...

```
private function onkeyboardDown(Event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {   
        switch (event.keyCode)
        { 
            case Keyboard.LEFT:
                vx = -5;
            break;
            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                vx = 5;
            break;
            case Keyboard.UP:
                vy = -5;
            break;
            case Keyboard.DOWN:
                vy = 5;
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Event` != `event`
Just change first string to

```
private function onkeyboardDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not declare a variable - event. may need to rename Event to event.